# Can I change kubernetes node ssh port

Tags: kubernetes, azure-aks

I'm using Kubernetes in Azure (ACS) and would like to know if it's possible to change the SSH port on the node VM's. I'd like to protect against brute-force attacks on the default SSH port (port 22) but I don't want to ruin any intra-cluster communication mechanisms. I would be happy to use acs-engine if that would make any difference.

Comment: After being provisioned, kube itself doesn't use port 22. Also, I have not used kube in azure but would think a bastion host configuration for ssh should be possible/desirable, and having ssh on the nodes exposed publicly should not be necessary.

Answer (score 0):

Foremost, I agree 100% with JonahB that exposing the Nodes to the wild Internet is an unnecessary risk. *I hesitate to even put this in an "answer" box, as it's far more like a dirty hack, but it was too many characters to fit in a comment; that said:*

In theory, you could take advantage of the fact that with `kubelet` you have a remote-control API almost directly into the Linux kernel on those machines. A `DaemonSet` deployed into the cluster could volumeMount `/var/lib/dbus` and then use the systemd control socket to shutdown sshd.service, and then later either an update to the DS (or a separate one) could turn ssh back on for Nodes of your choosing if you did need to ssh in. Or volumeMount `/etc/ssh`, alter the config, then use that same control socket to restart sshd.service.

I have used a very similar trick to provision new systemd services on Nodes using a volumeMount and the [go-systemd](https://github.com/coreos/go-systemd#readme) library; by coincidence, I happen to have a gist of the [systemd daemon-reload](https://gist.github.com/mdaniel/235110889c16515e09615dde0ecc2717) part that I posted while answering a question similar to this one.